# Trouble with setting up a SPARQL search for celebrities on dbpedia

Tags: sparql

I am currently working on a project in python where I want to code a great amount of Dutch news articles. I want to scan these articles for news values, amongst which celebrity news. In order to do so, I wanted to us dbpedia to create a list of singers/actors/tv personalities/otherwise 'famous' people, in order to look for those names in my newspaper articles.

Thus, I am looking for a way to set up a SPARQL query that yields a list of names of celebrities. I found that for example in case of musicians, the OWL that I am looking for should be thing->person->artist->musical artist (for example), but I just cannot figure out how to get there. It would be ideal if I could just get a list of titles of wikipedia articles in a given OntologyClass (like, for example, Musical Artist or Celebrity), preferably in .json file format (which, as I understood, is one of the supported file formats).

Obviously, I have tried setting up a SPARQL search by myself, but up to this point, I only get error messages (that I cannot really make sense of, to be honest) instead of the results I am looking for. Can anyone tell me how I can set up a sparql query as described above (returning a list of names in a given ontology class) or how I can otherwise retrieve such a list of people?

I want to query the Dutch version of dbpedia by the way, http://nl.dbpedia.org

Unfortunately, I have only come this far:

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?name WHERE {
  ?label owl:type :MusicalArtist
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Query

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl:<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?name WHERE {
  ?label owl:type :MusicalArtist
}
```

There are a number of problems with this, and some of them would be detected by the endpoint or a query validator.  You use the prefix **:** in **:MusicalArtist**, but you didn't define it.  With your prefixes, that should be **dbpedia-owl:MusicalArtist**.  There's no **owl:type** property;  you want **rdf:type**, which can be abbreviated as **a** in SPARQL queries (as in "find ?artist such that is **a** musical artist").

### How to do this

I'd probably use a query something like the following.  There are a few bits in here that you might need to do some research to understand, such as the **;** notation, the filter using **langMatches** and **lang**, and the **str** in the projection, but those are all pretty straightforward and can be understood by looking at other queries that you can find online (e.g., on Stack Overflow), or by consulting the [SPARQL 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/).  This query works on the standard DBpedia endpoint at http://dbpedia.org/sparql

```sql
select (str(?name_) as ?name) {
  ?artist a dbo:MusicalArtist ;
          rdfs:label ?name_ .
  filter langMatches(lang(?name_), "en")
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%28str%28%3Fname_%29%20as%20%3Fname%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fartist%20a%20dbo%3AMusicalArtist%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname_%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fname_%29%2C%20%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

To get the results in JSON, you can select "JSON" as the result type at the endpoint, and you'll get a file with content like:

```
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["name"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [
    { "name": { "type": "literal", "value": "AK 47 Mayanja" }},
    { "name": { "type": "literal", "value": "AR-Ab" }},
    { "name": { "type": "literal", "value": "A Pass" }},
    ...
    { "name": { "type": "literal", "value": "Vance Joy" }},
    { "name": { "type": "literal", "value": "Vince Gill" }},
    { "name": { "type": "literal", "value": "Wayne Hussey" }} ] } }
```

To use this on the Dutch DBpedia endpoint, you'll need to define the **dbo:** prefix which isn't predefined there.  Additionally, the language filtering might not help, since there might not be as many English results.  Thus you might end up with something like:

```sql
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select (str(?name_) as ?name) {
  ?artist a dbo:MusicalArtist ;
          rdfs:label ?name_ .
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I'll see if I can figure out the rest by myself.

Comment: Can you help me with a further question? Why does this query not yield results?

select (str(?name_) as ?name) {
  ?person a dbo:celebrity ;
          rdfs:label ?name_ .
  filter langMatches(lang(?name_), "en")
}


I thought that by changing the artist to person, it should work... but there are no results.

And for a search in Dutch, should I just change the Default Data Set Name or should I also change the dbo etc?

Comment: @Chris I don't think the Dutch endpoint has rfds:label values with a language tag matching "en".  That's why I removed in the final query that I provided.  Changing `?artist` to `?person` won't have an effect, but `dbo:celebrity` might not be a class used on DBpedia.  Did you see it in use somewhere?

Comment: @Chris dbpedia-owl:Celebrity (or dbo:Celebrity) does appear to be a class (note that **case matters**, it's Celebrity, not celebrity). Running the query `describe dbpedia-owl:Celebrity` will show some data about it.  However, it doesn't appear that the Dutch DBpedia knows about any instances:  `select (count(*) as ?n) { ?x a dbpedia-owl:Celebrity }` returns 0.

Comment: Ah you're right, I used the correct code you provided but posted the wrong. It could very well be that dbo:celebrity is not used on Dutch wikipedia, I'll give it a try with some other dbo's. By the way, why does changing ?artist to ?person not change anything? I thought that was the whole idea of the hierarchy....

Comment: @Chris `?artist` and `?person` are just the variables.  Why would the name of the variable matter?  You wouldn't expect `int n = 42, m = 43; return n+m;` to behave differently from `int x = 42, y = 43; return x+y;` to behave differently, would you?  Changing variable names shouldn't change the results.  Changing `dbo:MusicalArtist` to `dbo:Celebrity` should *definitely* change the results, though, since those are the constant values.  Just like `int x = 42, y = 43; return x+y;` and `int x = 72, y = 43; return x+y;` would be very different, because the constant values are different.

Comment: Ah, I suddenly see how my change did not make any sense at all. Thanks!